# How to update a collection after parent is destroyed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I'm developing a Rails 3.2.13 application and I have two models:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :client_invoices, dependent: :nullify

  ...

end

class ClientInvoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :invoice

  ...

end
```

I was wondering if there is a way to make the ClientInvoices to know when their parent Invoice is been destroyed and call a private method to update their status.

I've tried to perform this in the after_destroy callback of the Invoice, by looping the collection and changing the status of each ClientInvoice, but the collection is already empty there.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: what about an around_destroy?

Comment: thanks @apneadiving for your response, but inside the around_destroy the client_invoices collection is empty, so I can't loop through them... why can this be?

Comment: get the collection before the destroy, loop it after

Answer (score 0):

**before_destroy** will work.

```
before_destroy :update_client_invoice_statue

private

def update_client_invoice_statue   
  client_invoices.each do |invoice|
    #... code to update the status of record
  end
end
```

**Note :** This before_destroy method should return **true** for proceeding the destruction of the object.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm going to give it a try ASAP

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I haven't had the chance to test it yet. It's in my todo list as soon as I finish some pending work I have. Thanks again!